# How does western model of human evolution fit with Vedic literature?

Tags: vedas, scripture, puranas, history

As per western model of human evolution, modern humans are more advanced than our ancestors thousands and millions years ago. Then how could our ancestors could have built up such a massive literature of Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads with knowledge of everything if they are considered to be primitive by western models of evolution?

Comment: There are multiple western models of evolution, which one are you talking about? Most of these are linear, some are cyclic. The cyclic ones come close to our history.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I'm saying about Darwin's theory of evolution, which says that first was a single cell organism which evolved into multicellular beings and humans evolved from apes

Comment: Suppose that the knowledge we have now somehow gets preserved upto next creation. Then if our ancestor of that creation get that knowledge isn't that advanced... similar is knowledge of Vedas and Vedantas... They are eternal...

Comment: @user5155835 All that human evolving from ape business is just a theory. We had a vanar sena, essentially intelligent monkeys, which fits nowhere in such cooked up theories.

Answer (score 7):

Darwin's theory of evolution states that there is a physical chain of birth from amoeba to man, meaning your great^great^^100-grandfather was a single cell organism.

Whereas padma purana mentions there are 8.4 million 'species' :

> jalaja nava-laksani sthavara laksa-vimsati krmayo rudra-sankhyakah
>   paksinam dasa-laksanam trimsal-laksani pasavah catur-laksani manusah

```
900,000 species of aquatics
2,000,000 species of plants
1,100,000 species of insects/worms/reptiles
1,000,000 species of birds
3,000,000 species of animals
400,000 species of humans
```

Note - this definition of species is different from modern one that implies reproducible offspring.

We believe that each soul migrates through one of these 84 lakh bodies, until it reaches human form when it can either obtain mukti, or fall back in samsara (either in higher worlds from satya-svarga-loka or in lower worlds from atala-patala-loka).

There are 3 types of knowledge :

- facts perceived by senses (pratyaksha)
- inferences based on previous facts perceived by brain (anumana)
- knowledge gained from shastras/vedas (shabdam)

In our own experience, we know that the first two are fallible and prone to error. Whereas shabdam has never been wrong so far and will never be  because it is apaurusheya (not created by anyone).

In modern theory of evolution, there are 2 knowledge types - facts & inferences :

- facts - DNA resemblance between apes & humans, gene mutation, fossil
  records
- inference - amoeba's great^n-grandon son had features of
  fish, whose great^n-grandson had features of ape, whose
  great^n-grandson is now human

The facts cannot be argued, but the inference can. I can make another inference that the atma/soul migrates from one lower form to another in each birth, just like a student going from 1st grade to 12th. The curriculum (DNA) is very close between 1st grade (amoeba) & 2nd grade (fish), or 11th grade(ape) and 12th (human), otherwise students cannot understand the new syllabus easily. Within each grade, there are many subjects and specialties that students can adapt to (gene mutation) to based on their environment (natural selection) and the best students get the highest marks, while others are demoted to lower grade (survival of fittest).

It is common knowledge that science deals with physical matters, while religion deals with spirituality. So most inferences that western theories make are centered around the body, because science only accepts first 2 types of knowledge (senses and intuition) while eastern theories are centered around soul, so they accept the 3rd type of knowledge (vedas).

In short, Darwin came pretty close to figuring out the spiritual theory of evolution. He himself mentions in the landmark Origin of Species book that his works are speculative in nature. But atheists nowadays have used him as the mascot to push their agendas.

Comment: So, what do you want to say? Is there any connection between them?

Comment: Isn't that clear from what I said ? Vedas say there is spiritual evolution where soul migrates from one body (ape) to another body (man). Darwin says there is physical evolution where one body (ape) gives birth to another body(man). The progression of bodies is similar in both, but the method is different.

Comment: so you're saying that we've really physically evolved from apes?

Comment: what ? that is the exact opposite of what i'm saying

Comment: @Ajay - no. 'Evolution' is used in the sense of Darwin's theory of evolution, which infers a physical connection between different species. I'm talking about spiritual connection between souls, inhabiting different bodies in each janma

Comment: @NarayanaSharma, what ? why is DNA an illusion..

Comment: DNA does not say that. All DNA says is that there is resemblance. The physical chain of birth from amoeba to man is an inference based on DNA facts.

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever read about Evolution in Hinduism. However, how Vedas are superior to Pratyaksha and Anumana? Or do Hindu Philosophies accept Sabda to be more authentic than Pratyaksha and Anumana because those philosophies not only says soul exists but also soul can be realized?

Comment: @NaveenKick, because both Pratyaksha and Anumana have proven themselves to be unreliable, but Vedas have never been unreliable. Also, you don't need Vedas to tell you to eat.. you'll automatically eat when you're hungry (pratyaksha), and you don't need Vedas to tell you that food will satisfy hunger.. you'll automatically know that after the first time you eat (Anumana), but you need Vedas to tell you to Bathe before Eating (Snathva Bhunjeetha), because you don't know that doing otherwise (bed coffee, bed breakfast) etc. lead to diseases.

Comment: There are several other philosophies like Buddhism which accept only two Pramanas, Pratyaksha and Anumana, how do you deal with those philosophies? Also some say Pratyaksha and Anumana can be distorted so they are unreliable. But in my opinion even Vedas can also be distorted like Arya Samajis do.

Comment: @NaveenKick, it is very simple to deal with the other philosophies - they are wrong. not in the sense that they are false or incorrect, but they cannot answer all questions that plague humans. they are like the 9th step in a 10 step ladder. Thinking that they are the final step is what causes problems. Yes, the explanation of Vedas can be distorted, but not Vedas themselves. That's why we have to use Sruti , Smriti and teachings of acharyas all together. Some say 'Discard everything other than Sruti if it contradicts Sruti' - the problem is the Sruti you learnt itself may be distorted.

Comment: @NaveenKick, anumana is inference based on previous facts. suppose yesterday the street was dry. and it rained. then street became wet. we make connection that rain caused wet. tomorrow street is wet, so you make anumana that cause could have been rain. you still don't know for sure, like you said, someone could have poured water on entire street. that's why anumana cannot be trusted completely 100%. it is practical enough for daily life, but not for Vedanta. only way to 100% trust is a trusted authority like weather channel saying that it rained. the only 100% trust-able authority is Vedas.

Comment: So, the example given by me is anumana pramana. Isn't it?

Comment: Please reply me

Comment: @NaveenKick, it does fall under Anumana, but since you specifically asked about Artapatti, i didn't know what it was and researched it. if smoke then fire is anumana. this is almost sure. but in artapatti, if wet, then either rain or hose-pipe, that is doubt. both are inferences, but i think one is more sure than other.

Comment: Okay one small question, according to Darwin theory of evolution, many species became extinct. Even recently too, dodo birds went extinct. Now my question is, did those extinct species have soul?

Comment: @NaveenKick, yes of course, any living being is atma surrounded by body - only the body became extinct. earlier there were 8 ft tall men, nowadays they're mostly 6 ft. it is just changes according to yugas. What kind of question are you asking about Indus sites - whether those who died have a soul ??

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, Darwinian evolution occurs at a scale of millions of years, whereas the Vedas, Puranas, etc. are dated within the last 5000 years. There is no suggestion of any significant evolutionary transformation in humans in the last 5 millennia. However, this is also the answer to your question-- Darwinian evolution is at a larger timescale than the knowledge of our ancestors.

Secondly, it is surely a stretch to claim that this literature had a `knowledge of everything`. The texts you speak of describe rituals, philosophy and practices that were enlightened when they were first conceived, but can hardly be said to be accurate in the 21st century.

I hope you do not mean to treat mythology as history, and claim that a `vanar sena` can be legitimately fitted into our past as [@Amit Saxena](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4157/amit-saxena) suggests.

Comment: vedas/puranas are NOT dated within the last 5000 years. it only seems so because written language came about then. Vedas are timeless. The Hindu time scale is much larger than any Western/Darwinian theory. Itihasas and Puranas have specific dates. If you think 'mythology' is imaginary stories, you're wrong.

Comment: [@ram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4435/ram): Sure, if you follow a literal interpretation of Hindu texts, then I partly agree with [your answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12445/5727)-- both the models cannot be reconciled and one of them must be inaccurate. Darwinian evolution makes its claims based on a significant amount of [evidence](http://necsi.edu/projects/evolution/evidence/evidence_intro.html), such a fossil remains and studies on existing organisms.

Comment: like i mentioned, evidence (pratyaksham) is one thing, inference (anumanam) is a completely different thing. both are fallible. yet, nobody is refuting the evidence in case of evolution. all i'm saying is that the inference based upon the evidence is wrong.